# mikTeX - pdflatex - texmf.fndb on a network

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I'm hoping to move our MikTeX Installation to a shared Network Directory. Is this possible?

The Network Administrators want to configure "their" file Server so that it is read-only. This seems to cause a problem - pdflatex appears to want write or exec access to `texmf.fndb`. Can that be? Nothing should update the file - I've configured this installtion to disallow automatic updates.

Question 2 - what is the difference between `accessing` or `loading` a file?

Here's some debug output (error is at the end):

```
[7556] 124 [pdflatex.core]: accessing file I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini: OK
[7556] 124 [pdflatex.core]: MIKTEX_USERSTARTUPFILE => null
...
[7556] 124 [pdflatex.core]: accessing file C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini: NOK
[7556] 133 [pdflatex.core]: parsing: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini...
[7556] 133 [pdflatex.core]: opening file I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini (2 0x1 1 1)
[7556] 135 [pdflatex.core]: setting env MIKTEX_COMMONSTARTUPFILE=I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\config\miktexstartup.ini
[7556] 135 [pdflatex.core]: registering user TEXMF root:    I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf
[7556] 135 [pdflatex.core]: now a common TEXMF root: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf
...
[7556] 201 [pdflatex.core]: search vector fmt:
[7556] 201 [pdflatex.core]:    0: O:\REP_TEST\FHTST\bka_test_box\RDF
[7556] 201 [pdflatex.core]:    1: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex/data/le/pdfTeX
[7556] 201 [pdflatex.core]:    2: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex/data/le/
[7556] 201 [pdflatex.core]:    3: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\localtexmf\miktex/data/le/pdfTeX
[7556] 201 [pdflatex.core]:    4: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\localtexmf\miktex/data/le/
[7556] 201 [pdflatex.core]: file system search: filename=pdflatex.fmt, directory=O:\REP_TEST\ZZZZ\tex_file_dir\RDF
[7556] 202 [pdflatex.core]: accessing file O:\REP_TEST\ZZZZ\tex_file_dir\RDF\pdflatex.fmt: NOK
[7556] 203 [pdflatex.core]: accessing file I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex/data/le\texmf.fndb: OK
[7556] 203 [pdflatex.core]: loading fndb: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex/data/le\texmf.fndb
[7556] 204 [pdflatex.core]: Access is denied. 
[7556] 
[7556] Function: CreateFileW
[7556] Result: 5
[7556] Data: I:\Tools\Miktex\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex/data/le\texmf.fndb
[7556] Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp:209
[7556] 204 [pdflatex.core]: MIKTEX_DEBUG_BREAK => null
[7556] 213 [pdflatex.core]: unloading fndb 0223FDC8
[7556] 219 [pdflatex.core]: uninitializing core library
```

Comment: You should better ask regarding the assess denied error on the miktex bug-tracker (but imho the fndb should be in a writable place).

Comment: @Ulrike - thanks. It happens that there is an entry there. I didn't think to look.  The URL is (at this time): https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2264/

Comment: @Ulrike - Pardon my asking, but if I don't want my System to automatically update itself, why should the system *fndb be writable/updatable?